# How to get string's byte length?

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I have a string like this:

```
string a1 = "{`name`:`санкт_петербург`,`shortName`:`питер`,`hideByDefault`:false}";
```

`a1. length` shows that string length is **68**, which is not true: Cyrillic symbols are twice as big (because of UTF-16 encoding, I presume), therefore the real length of this string is **87**.

I need to either get the number of Cyrillic symbols in the string or get real string length in any other way.

Comment: *All* .NET strings are UTF16. *All* characters are 2 bytes long. `.Length` returns the number of characters, not bytes. The string has 68 characters and takes 136 bytes

Comment: What about `Encoding.GetByteCount`?

Comment: Even with "ASCII" characters, the length and size remain the same. For `name`, the length is 4 and uses 8 bytes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, all characters in UTF16 aren't 2 bytes long. Some are longer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson typically emojis and Chinese. In the most common case encountered outside Asia, it's 2 bytes - Unless you are Tacoma Airport, where all announcements are also in Chinese

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Aye, and the point is you can't just multiply the string's length by 2 to get the number of bytes - you MUST use the `GetByteCount()` method (or convert to byte array and check its length, but of course that would be horribly inefficient if all you want is the byte length).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The .NET Framework uses the UTF-16 encoding (represented by the UnicodeEncoding class) to represent characters and string

So `a1.Length` is in UTF-16 code units ([What's the difference between a character, a code point, a glyph and a grapheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331819/whats-the-difference-between-a-character-a-code-point-a-glyph-and-a-grapheme)). Cyrillic characters, being in the base BMP (Base Multilingual Plane), all use a single code unit (so a single `char`). Many emoji for example use TWO code units (two `char`, 4 bytes!)... They aren't in the BMP. See for example https://ideone.com/ASDORp.

If you want the size IN BYTES, `a1.Length * 2` clearly is the length :-) If you want to know in UTF8 (a very common encoding, NOT USED INTERNALLY BY .NET, but very used by the web, xml, ...) how many bytes it would be `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(a1)`

Comment: 2 bytes, right? Not 2 char.

Comment: Yes, `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(a1)` works. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman New emoji are 2 char, 4 bytes For example  is 2xchars. See https://ideone.com/ASDORp

Comment: @MrScapegrace works for what? You can't mix UTF8 and UTF16 in a single string, they are always UTF16. Your assumption about the string length was wrong. `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount()` returns the size in bytes if the entire string was converted from UTF16 to UTF8 first.