# The actual length of a string

Tags: c#, string, size, ascii

I have a `string` which consist of the mixture of Chinese characters and displayable ASCII codes.

```
string str = "Test測試123";
```

When I use `str.Length` or `str.ToCharArray()`, it all return the Chinese character each as **1 character**! Which is not true because any Chinese character is **2 byte**!

Even if I try `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)`, it just give me **63**s in **ALL** the Chinese characters!!! And it turned out to be the same result as `Length` or `ToCharArray()`!

Which is the **wrong** result for my purpose!!!

Is there any way to get the **actual** length of a string!?

In the example I just given: 11 instead of 9!?

Comment: *composed of 2 ASCII codes* no... If converted to UTF8 then chinese characters are two bytes... something very different. Try `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str)`

Comment: That's what I mean! Updated!

Comment: @bommelding: I'm sorry that I don't really understand what you mean!

Comment: Strings in .NET are UTF16 by default. For this reason, the size of the string (in bytes) will be different than its length (number of characters). Which one do you need?

Comment: I tried `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str)`, but it give me a size **bigger** than what it actually is!!! In the example I'd given: 13 instead of 11! Where that extra 2 come from!?!?!?

Comment: @Martin I would like to get the, how could I say, **size of the byte array it use to store the string!?** For the example I'd given: For each Chinese character it use 2 bytes, and 1 byte for each other characters. So it add up to 11 total! Could that be done!? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Length in the Unicode world is always fun... What Length do you need? For example:

```
string str = "";

// Length in UTF-16 code units
int len = str.Length; // 2

// Length in bytes, if encoded in UTF16, as done by .NET
int len2 = str.Length * 2; // 4

// Length in bytes, if encoded in UTF8
int len3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str); // 4

// Length in unicode code points
int len4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetByteCount(str) / 4; // 1
```

Note that there is a fifth length: Length in number of grapheme cluster, that is even more complex to calculate, because some codepoints can "merge" together, and a sixth: Length in number of Glyphs.

Now, your string has `len` equal to `9`, `len2` equal to `18`, `len3` (so the length in bytes if converted to UTF8) equal to `13`, `len4` equal to 9.

Nearly all the chinese characters are in the Basic Multilingual Plane of the Unicode standard, so they have a length of 1 UTF-16 code unit, and they are mappable to 2 or 3 bytes in UTF8.

Some interesting reference: [What's the difference between a character, a code point, a glyph and a grapheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331819/whats-the-difference-between-a-character-a-code-point-a-glyph-and-a-grapheme)
.

Ah... and please forget about the `Encoding.ASCII`. Live like it doesn't exist. It probably isn't what you think it is. Even if you lived in the old MS DOS world with its funny characters, that wasn't ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Which give me the idea!  It's all about the encoding! In my case, it's BIG5! So if I use **`Encoding.GetEncoding("BIG5").GetByteCount(str)`**, it would give me the answer I'm looking for! Thank you very **VERY** much!!!

Comment: "Live like it doesn't exist.": Yes! ASCII is required by certain standards. If such a standard is not referenced, it's almost certainly not ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget as you wrote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Space of Chinese's width is double as English, but character code's length is another story, UTF-8 Chinese take three bytes and English is always one byte.

```
//only for UTF-8
string s = "計算字串的長度this is a test";
int sLength = s.Length; //length is 21
int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s); // byte count is 35
int chineseCount = (byteCount - sLength)/2; //Chinese count is 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on @eldercharlie

```
int len = text.Length;
int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text);
int width = (len + byteCount) / 2;
```