# Is there a way to iterate through std::u8string character by character?

Tags: c++, string, encoding, utf-8, c++20

I am facing difficulties while using C++20's `std::u8string`. However, I believe the problem also occurs with the older `std::string`.

UTF-8 is a multi-byte sequence encoding method that can represent a single Unicode character with multiple bytes.

Since `std::u8string` is implemented using `std::basic_string`, the class lacks specific methods for iterating character by character.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691715/) on obtaining the correct length of `std::u8string`, but the answers did not help because they either 'converted' the encoding into another, or were optimized solely for obtaining the length of the string.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::u8string utf8 = u8"α.β";
    for (auto c : utf8)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << (0xff & c) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Note: The above program uses the bit-wise `AND` operator to print the hex code properly. However, I want to iterate over the string with an `int` datatype to read multi-byte characters.*

The above example uses two multi-byte-represented characters, `'α'` and `'β'`.

After compiling with g++11 on Ubuntu, the example program clearly outputs 5 times instead of 3:

```
ce b1 2e ce b2
```

The sequence `ce b1` corresponds to `'α'`, and `ce b2` corresponds to `'β'`.

I don't want to convert the string into UTF-16 or UTF-32 by using `<codecvt>`, since it hurts performance to switch between encodings.

Is there a method for `std::u8string` to iterate the string character by character?

Comment: There isn't any such standard method. You can write one easily based on code in the answer you mention. However you probably don't need it. If you think you need it, please explain why. Most people who think they need this particular definition of "character" are mistaken.

Comment: Unless you want to write it yourself the easiest way is to use a library that provides the functionality to iterate over code points. I've used this one in the past and been satisfied.  https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#utf8next

Comment: What do you mean by "character"? Do you mean "Unicode codepoint"? Maybe you mean "grapheme cluster" (aka, what you see on screen that looks like a "character," but which could be composed of multiple code points)?

Comment: @NicolBolas I intended 'character' to refer to 'Unicode codepoint'.

Comment: @dolmok C++ does not provide anyway to translate the bytes of the string into code points. You have to write that code (or use a third party library).

Comment: There's nothing in C++ to do it for you. However, I have very good news for you: UTF-8 is very simple to work with. The Wikipedia article on UTF-8 explains how it works, and it shouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to write a simple algorithm for iterating over a string, one character at a time.

Comment: But the bad news: codepoints are mostly useless if you take them one at a time: it is well know e.g. that Apple and Microsoft uses two different Unicode normalization for same character: one with 2 codepoints and one with just a single one. users are confused (and BTW again Unicode standard) if you give two different results for the same character.