# Will we have a size_t strlen(const char8_t*) in a future C++ version

Tags: c++, c-strings, strlen, char8-t

`char8_t` in C++20 fixes some problems of `char`, so I was considering using `char8_t` instead of `char` for utf8 text (e.g. text from command line). But then I noticed that `strlen` was not specified in the standard to be used with `char8_t`, actually none of the functions in the cstring library are. Can I expect this to happen in a next standard update? Or is `char8_t` never intended to replace `char` in the way I had in mind?

Comment: "Always in motion, is future."

Comment: The first problem is that "length" is a bit ambiguous for a UTF-8 string. The API we get should be separate from the C one.

Comment: UTF-8 or Unicode generally can be quite complicated. See all the terms, how a Unicode string can be split into smaller units. It is a little bit more complicated than plain old char arrays ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331819/whats-the-difference-between-a-character-a-code-point-a-glyph-and-a-grapheme

Comment: You might be interested in following and/or contributing to [SG-16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) if you care a lot about this. That's probably the best pathway to standardization.

Comment: @chris: "*The first problem is that "length" is a bit ambiguous for a UTF-8 string.*" It's not ambiguous at all. Even in UTF encodings, it is perfectly valid to NUL-terminate such strings. Every `u8`, `u` and `U` literal in C++ is NUL-terminated, so it's a standard C++ convention. Obviously, `basic_string/_view` are not, and many APIs aren't NUL-terminated either, but even `std::u8string`'s constructor that takes a single `const char8_t*` expects NUL-termination.

Comment: @NicolBolas, What I was referring to is that depending whom you ask, a person might expect a `strlen` working on UTF-8 to return the number of bytes, code points, ECGs, or possibly something else I've forgotten. It was a naming point rather than a technical one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of the [P0482](https://wg21.link/p0482) and [P1423](https://wg21.link/p1423) `char8_t` proposals.

The intent of those proposals was to introduce the `char8_t` type with the same level of support present for `char16_t` and `char32_t` and then to follow up with additional functionality later.  These proposals were adopted late in the C++20 development cycle (at the San Diego and Cologne meetings respectively), so there wasn't opportunity to deliver additional features for C++20.

One of the directives for [SG16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) as described in [P1238](https://wg21.link/p1238) is to standardize new encoding aware text container and view types.  Work is progressing in this area and we hope to deliver it for C++23.  It is hoped that these new containers and views will supplant much raw string handling in C++.

With regard to `strlen` specifically, `strlen` is a C API.  [N2231](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2231.htm) is a proposal to add `char8_t` support to C (again, at the same level as the existing support for `char16_t` and `char32_t`).  That proposal has not yet been accepted by WG14.  Assuming it is eventually accepted, then it would make sense to follow up with additional `char8_t`-based C string management functions (perhaps enhancing support for `char16_t` and `char32_t` as well).

At present, I'm working on completing an implementation of [N2231](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2231.htm) in gcc and glibc.  Once that is complete, I intend to submit a revision of N2231 to WG14.

You can help!  [SG16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) is an open group.  Please feel free to subscribe to our mailing list, join us on Slack, share your ideas, needs, and wants, and write proposals for new functionality (we can help with how to do that).

Answer (score 1):

These new char types are intended to use C++ string template `std::basic_string`, namely to define `std::u8string`. So the best in your case is use C++ strings.

As for the future support of `char8_t` in cstring library, I suppose this question is more suitable to the future C standard. I'm afraid, it will not be an easy and will be unlikely update, since C does not have overloaded functions, and this update will require new functions like `c8slen` in addition to `strlen` and `wcslen`.

Answer (score 1):

`char8_t` is intended for UTF-8-encoded strings. As such, APIs that consume them will be *assumed* by users to be Unicode aware on some level. Quite a lot of the [contents of the `<cstring>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) would be inappropriate for `char8_t`, as their behavior is very much not in line with Unicode (would `strcmp` do proper Unicode collation?).

If you want access to functions that work similarly to the `<cstring>` functions, then you'll find [`std::char_trait<char8_t>` to contain some useful ones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits), in particular `length` (exactly like `strlen`) and `compare` (explicitly lexicographical). Most of the rest of `<cstring>` can be handled adequately through C++ algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

0 can still act as null-terminator in utf8-strings, so technically nothing prevents you (except a lack of appropriate function) from using strlen to count the amount of bytes(!) in utf8 sequence. If you want to find the number of chars you would need a separate function.

Comment: How does this answer the question? After a quick read, I'm confused. Did you mean to comment on an existing post here? If so, wait until you earn the comment-everywhere privilege.