Split the word using bigram, trigram
I have this text file:
worked
working
works
tested
tests
find
found

It contains a million words without spaces. It may contain unicode characters.
The longest word is "working":
awk '{print length, $0}' test.txt | sort -nr | head -1
7 working

I need to create bigram, trigram (Max 7 columns)
w,wo,wor,work,worke,worked,
w,wo,wor,work,worki,workin,working
w,wo,wor,work,works,,
t,te,tes,test,teste,tested,
t,te,tes,test,tests,,
f,fi,fin,find,,,,
f,fo,fou,foun,found,,

preferably in awk (because it's fast)

Those are not bigrams and trigrams. Do you mean you want all prefixes up to a fixed length, like your output suggests; or is that an example of something you don't want?

If your real input can contain unicode characters, then include unicode characters in your sample input/output. You need to provide a [mcve] we can test with so we know if a given solution works or not and handling unicode correctly can be a differentiator.

A straightforward approach would be:
awk -v n=7 -v OFS=, \
  '{s=$0; len=length(s); for (i=1;i<=len;i++) $i=substr(s,1,i); $n=$n}1'

w,wo,wor,work,worke,worked,
w,wo,wor,work,worki,workin,working
w,wo,wor,work,works,,
t,te,tes,test,teste,tested,
t,te,tes,test,tests,,
f,fi,fin,find,,,
f,fo,fou,foun,found,,

Tested on GNU Awk 5.3.0, mawk 1.3.4 20240819, and The One True Awk version 20240728.

I was surprised how fast it was assigning to $i in your code, that's faster than what I did which was to constantly append to a string variable. I know updating a variable isn't fast as awk has to re-allocate the memory for the variable each time it gets longer but I still expected it to be faster than updating $i which causes awk to re-split $0 on each loop iteration.

Ahhhh, I just realised that splitting $0 is fast in this case since there's only 1 field on each line AND most awks do lazy field splitting so, given your code which doesn't do anything in the loop to require a re-split $0, during the loop they'll just note that field splitting needs to happen and then do it once after the loop completes .

Fyi, only gawk handles (some) Unicode characters right, mawk and nawk/original awk split the bytes.

If you don't know the max length of the string in advance you could use:
awk '
 BEGIN {max_length=1}; { a[NR]=$1; m=length($1); if (m > max_length) {max_length=m} }
 END { for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {for (j=1; j<=max_length;j++) {if(j<=length(a[i])){printf "%s", substr(a[i],1,j)}; if(j<max_length){ printf "%s", "," } }; print ""} }
' file
w,wo,wor,work,worke,worked,
w,wo,wor,work,worki,workin,working
w,wo,wor,work,works,,
t,te,tes,test,teste,tested,
t,te,tes,test,tests,,
f,fi,fin,find,,,
f,fo,fou,foun,found,,


Nitpick - print "" is better than printf "\n" as it uses the value that ORS has rather than hard-coding the value, "\n", that you think/hope that ORS will have and so it'll work, for example, even on platforms that use "\r\n" for the ORS.

Using any awk (for English language chars input at least) if you already know the max length of an input string:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; maxLen=7 }
{
    curLen = length($0)
    out = substr($0,1,1)
    for ( i=2; i<=curLen; i++ ) {
        out = out OFS substr($0,1,i)
    }
    $0 = out
    $maxLen = $maxLen
    print
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
w,wo,wor,work,worke,worked,
w,wo,wor,work,worki,workin,working
w,wo,wor,work,works,,
t,te,tes,test,teste,tested,
t,te,tes,test,tests,,
f,fi,fin,find,,,
f,fo,fou,foun,found,,

otherwise with a 2-pass approach to first calculate that max length:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ curLen = length($0) }
NR == FNR {
    if ( curLen > maxLen ) {
        maxLen = curLen
    }
    next
}
{
    out = substr($0,1,1)
    for ( i=2; i<=curLen; i++ ) {
        out = out OFS substr($0,1,i)
    }
    $0 = out
    $maxLen = $maxLen
    print
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file file
w,wo,wor,work,worke,worked,
w,wo,wor,work,worki,workin,working
w,wo,wor,work,works,,
t,te,tes,test,teste,tested,
t,te,tes,test,tests,,
f,fi,fin,find,,,
f,fo,fou,foun,found,,

With the above, I

Only call length() once before the loop starts so awk doesn't call it on every loop iteration,
Only populate $0 outside of the loop to avoid awk re-splitting and/or re-constructing $0 on every loop iteration,
Only loop up to the length of the current line, not the max length of all lines,
Only create empty fields up to the max number of fields 1 time per input line by using $maxLen = $maxLen after the loop, and
Only store 1 line at a time in memory.

so it'll be portable, fast, and work for any size of input file.
@tripleee points out in a comment that they got incorrect output on MacOS from the above script when using unicode characters. The default awk on MacOS is notoriously buggy and I don't have a Mac to test on so I'm not going to investigate that but FWIW here's what I see from the second script above given @tripleee's input and using gawk 5.3.0 on cygwin with LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8':
$ printf '%s\n' "người" "đặt" > file

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
n,ng,ngư,ngườ,người
đ,đặ,đặt,,

$ awk -b -f tst.awk file file
n,ng,ng▒,ngư,ngư▒,ngư▒,ngườ,người
▒,đ,đ▒,đ▒,đặ,đặt,,


$ printf '%s\n' 'résumé' 'zoölogy' > file

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
r,ré,rés,résu,résum,résumé,
z,zo,zoö,zoöl,zoölo,zoölog,zoölogy

$ awk -b -f tst.awk file file
r,r▒,ré,rés,résu,résum,résum▒,résumé
z,zo,zo▒,zoö,zoöl,zoölo,zoölog,zoölogy


$ printf '%s\n' $'re\u0301sume\u0301' > file

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
r,re,ré,rés,résu,résum,résume,résumé

$ awk -b -f tst.awk file file
r,re,re▒,ré,rés,résu,résum,résume,résume▒,résumé

Here;'s what -b does (from the gawk manual):

-b
--characters-as-bytes
Cause gawk to treat all input data as single-byte characters. In addition, all output written with print or printf is treated as
single-byte characters.
Normally, gawk follows the POSIX standard and attempts to process its input data according to the current locale (see Where You Are
Makes a Difference). This can often involve converting multibyte
characters into wide characters (internally), and can lead to problems
or confusion if the input data does not contain valid multibyte
characters. This option is an easy way to tell gawk, “Hands off my
data!”


The second script prints nothing for me on MacOS with input from stdin. The first misbehaves predictably with inputs like résumé or zoölogy.

@tripleee you can't do a 2-pass approach using stdin, you;d need to store the input in memory to calculate the max length before processing the input if you wanted to use stdin. The second problem sounds like an issue with your locale.

Oh sorry, I missed the two-pass construct there. My locale is en_US.UTF-8 and my Perl works fine with these Unicode strings.

If the OP says they have a problem handling Unicode strings I'll take a look but I don't have a Mac to test on. FWIW using gawk --posix on cygwin with the same locale you have I get the same output as your perl script produces. The default awk on MacOS is notoriously buggy so maybe this is just one of those bugs.

Unfortunately, I get the same crippled output with LC_ALL=C

With brew install gawk I get correct output for these, as long as the input is normalized to a single code point per glyph. With iconv -t utf-8-mac file | gawk '...' I get r,re,ré,rés,résu,résum,résume,résumé i.e. it (predictably) regards the combining accent as a separate character.

The OP does mention "It may contain unicode characters" though perhaps they only mean simple composed Latin-1 characters.

Ah, so it does, I missed that. It would have made a lot of sense for them to include some in the example then!

Perfectly agree!

I was hoping the Vietnamese example would force the accents to be separate but alas, all of the ones in my sample have simple composed representations.

I updated my answer to mention your comment and show gawk running on the sample input you provided, thank.

Try also printf '%s\n' $'re\u0301sume\u0301'

@tripleee done and I added the output with and without the -b option to the end of my answer. Do either of those look like what you expected?

Both of them demonstrate the problem I'm hoping to highlight, i.e. that Awk inherently does not know anything about Unicode grapheme clusters.

Assuming perl does, can you add that case to your answer so I can see what the expected output should be? Idk about awk but I certainly don't know anything about "Unicode grapheme clusters" so an explanation of that issue would be appreciated too if you wouldn't mind.

Thanks for prodding, I added a simple example to my answer.

Ah, got it now, thanks.

Looks like a decent discussion of graphemes, etc. at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27331819/1745001.

A Unicode-safe approach using ruby (max=7-1: zero-based, length-1: trailing newline). $_ holds the row, which is enabled by -n
% ruby -ne 'BEGIN{max=7-1}
    sep=""
    (0..max).each do |i|
      if i < $_.length-1 
        printf("%s%s", sep,$_[0..i])
        sep=","
      else printf("%s", sep)
      end
    end
    puts ""' file

Note, use $_.grapheme_clusters[0..i].join (with a slight performance hit) if you're really serious about Unicode (split by graphemes, split emoji characters).
output
r,ré,rés,résu,résum,résumé,
z,zo,zoö,zoöl,zoölo,zoölog,zoölogy
w,wo,wor,work,worke,worked,
w,wo,wor,work,worki,workin,working
w,wo,wor,work,works,,
t,te,tes,test,teste,tested,
t,te,tes,test,tests,,
f,fi,fin,find,,,
f,fo,fou,foun,found,,

Data
% cat file
résumé
zoölogy
worked
working
works
tested
tests
find
found


Awk doesn't cope very well with Unicode compose sequences. Maybe turn to Perl for a convenient replacement.
Here's a brief test with a random string in Vietnamese, which uses lots of accents.
bash$ printf '%s\n' "người" "đặt" | xxd
00000000: 6e67 c6b0 e1bb 9d69 0ac4 91e1 bab7 740a  ng.....i......t.

Here's a demonstration of how nawk behaves with this input:
bash$ printf '%s\n' "người" "đặt" |
> awk -vn=7 -vOFS=, '{s=$0; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) $i=i<=length(s)? substr(s,1,i): ""}1'
n,ng,ng?,ngư,ngư?,ngư?,ngườ
?,đ,đ?,đ?,đặ,đặt,

Here is a quick and dirty Perl implementation:
bash$ printf '%s\n' "người" "đặt" |
> perl -CSD -ne 'BEGIN { $n = 7 }
> chomp; $sep = ""; for my $i (1..$n) {
>   print ($_ =~ "\\X{$i}" ? "$sep$&" : "$sep"); $sep = ","; }
> print "\n";'
n,ng,ngư,ngườ,người,,
đ,đặ,đặt,,,,

Here's a demonstration with a more familiar English (well, loan) word.
bash$ printf '%s\n' $'re\u0301sume\u0301' |
> perl -CSD -ne 'BEGIN { $n = 7 }
> chomp; $sep = ""; for my $i (1..$n) {
>   print ($_ =~ "\\X{$i}" ? "$sep$&" : "$sep"); $sep = ","; }
> print "\n";'
r,ré,rés,résu,résum,résumé,

In case it's not obvious, Perl crucially knows that U+0301 is a combining character which should be joined graphically with the preceding base character, and so regards the resulting cluster as a single character (or more properly grapheme) as far as the regex \X is concerned. Because Awk doesn't have this knowledge, it cannot do that. (Perhaps see also Unicode equivalence on Wikipedia.)
If you really want bigrams and trigrams, not prefixes up to a particular length, that's easy, too.
bash$ printf '%s\n' "người" "đặt" |
> perl -CSD -ne 'chomp; $sep = "";
> for my $i (0..length($_)) {
>     break unless ($_ =~ "\\X{$i}\\K\\X{2}");
>     print "$sep$&";
>     $sep = ",";
>     print ($_ =~ "\\X{$i}\\K\\X{3}" ? "$sep$&" : "");
> } print "\n";'
ng,ngư,gư,gườ,ườ,ười,ời
đặ,đặt,ặt


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/./&\n&/
        :a;s/(.+)\n(\1.)/\1,\2\n\2/;ta
        s/\n.*|$/,,,,,,/;s/,/\n/7;P;d' file

Introduce a newline as marker, then compare before and after the marker plus a further character and iterate throughout the length of the word building up a set of words.
Append additional commas and discard unwanted columns.
